# AngularJS: ng-click not working on mobile

Tags: javascript

How come my verify button is not working on any mobile devices. It was perfectly working on desktop browser. Hope you can help me guys even I did not share my codes in here. I was working on a private company. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `ng-touch` ?

Comment: yes, Still no luck for me. :(

Comment: ng-click="getPost('click', $event)"

Comment: var app = angular.module('app',['ngSanitize','ngTouch']);

var global_flag = 0;

 app.controller('controller', function($scope,$http,$location) { 
   
   $scope.getPost = function() {